# Reserving Package Namespace Collision on Android Marketplace aka Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, android-package-managers

I am starting to encounter situations where the package namespace I'd like to use appears to be already taken. In some cases, it's odd, because it's a com.* name, and it feels like someone is "domain" squatting my package name space!

This question isn't about squatting... I'm not sure if it's open-ended or if there is currently a solution I haven't been able to find on google:

**On Android Market, is there a way to allow only people from your company to post to the package namespace**: `com.yourdomain.*`

Answer (score 0):

I afraid not, but it seem like a strange issue, Can you post exact response from Android Market when they rejects your package name?